# Constant-Time Algorithm for Finding Greatest Factor of Odd Composite Number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given an odd number, what is the quickest (constant-time) algorithm for finding its largest factor and suppose you can call a helper function B which takes as its input (N, k) and outputs True iff N has a factor greater than or equal to k? 
Obviously, the factor cannot be itself.

Comment: Er, why do you suspect that a constant-time algorithm even exists?

Comment: That wouldn't be a constant time function though. That helper function would allow you to perform a binary search on the largest factor of N, but that is not constant time.

Comment: Since the size of the factor depends on $N$ (it can have up to $\Omega(\log N)$ bits), there can be no constant-time algorithm solving this problem. It's easy to find one which runs with $O(\log N)$ queries to the helper function (just perform binary search for the largest factor)

Comment: I doubt there is a constant time algorithm for this. However, I think that if you had a function $B'(N,k)$ which returns $1$ iff $N$ has a factor less than or equal to $k$ you would have more luck. 

This is because the "probability" some large number has no factors smaller than $M$ tends to zero at a rate asymptotic to $\frac{1}{\log M}$. This can change the way you partition your search space. The worst-case running time won't change, but you might be able to reach $O(\log \log n)$ average-case running time.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are right. It cannot be constant time.

Comment: Cross-/reposted [on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13773/98).

Answer (score 1):

I followed up on my comment, and asked a question (with my altered definition of $B$) on [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

I eventually did some work on it myself, and found that it is possible to solve the problem in $O(\log \log N)$ average-case. (If the proof is correct, anyway.)

[Here is a link to the question/answer.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13773/time-complexity-of-finding-the-largest-factor-of-a-number-using-a-specific-orac)

The thing is, I don't know much about number theory. I discovered that fact about the probability a number has no factors lower than $M$ from some other questions on stack exchange (specifically: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284500/probability-of-a-number-not-having-factors-below-n), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94645/expected-smallest-prime-factor)).

I suspect that some more in-depth number-theoretic analysis can make the algorithm run even faster in the average case.